# IntellijIDEA - Android - JUnit - Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info

Tags: java, android, maven, junit

> Running tests
>   Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{spr/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
>   Empty test suite.

I got this error during running test method in JUnit 4 class. It's an example of method:

```
@Test
public void testPriceSum1(){
    products.add(new Product("","",1L,"",1L));
    products.add(new Product("","",2L,"",1L));
    ProductsBasketManager productsBasketManager = new ProductsBasketManager(products);
    long result = productsBasketManager.priceSum();
    assertEquals(3L, result);
}
```

When i change the name of method on testPriceSum it works fine but when the name is diffrent it doesn't work. I have priceSum() method in tested class. Where is the problem I am using Maven and it is Android project.

EDIT.
I have **resolved** this problem, it was because of wrong Run/Debug configuration. When I changed name of the test method i didn't do the same in configuration.